# Task Continuation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library

I have a Web API that returns a list of people:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{
    var people = await _PeopleRepo.GetAll();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, people);
}
```

I have a console application that I'd like to be able to call so that it first gets the people, then iterates over them calling their ToString() method, and then completing.

I have the following method to get the people:

```
static async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPeople()
{
    List<Person> peopleList = null;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:38263/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("People");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            peopleList = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Person>>();
        }
    }

    return peopleList;
}
```

I then have a second function to print the list:

```
static void PrintPeopleList(List<Person> people)
{
    if (people == null)
    {
        Console.Write("No people to speak of.");
        return;
    }

    people.ForEach(m => Console.WriteLine(m.ToString()));
}
```

I tried using a task factory to first download the people list with GetAllPeople() and then supply the results to PrintPeopleList() when the response is back but the compiler gives an ambiguous invocation error:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetAllPeople()).ContinueWith((t) => PrintPeopleList(t.Result));
```

Am I way off?

Comment: `GetAllPeople` already returns a `Task` so you don't need to use `StartNew`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call

```
List<Person> persons = await GetAllPeople();
PrintPeopleList(persons);
```

Comment: With PrintPeopleList() present, the service method doesn't appear to be called. If I comment the call to PrintPeopleList() out, it does call into the service method. Any idea why that is?

Comment: That can't be true.  Maybe some magic? How `PrintPeopleList` relates with service call?

Comment: None, since it only iterates over a List supplied to it and Console.WriteLine's the ToString() of each list item.